# "Skia shader compilation error"

Tags: command-line, window

I've been getting the error "Skia shader compilation error" in my term window for the last two days. It regularly overwrites my screen. I have no idea what it means or how to get rid of it. And just now, this popped up:

"Passwords sqlite error 2067, errno 0: UNIQUE constraint failed: logins.origin_url, logins.username_element, logins.username_value, logins.password_element, logins.signon_realm, sql: INSERT INTO logins (origin_url, action_url, username_element, username_value, password_element, password_value, submit_element, signon_realm, date_created, blacklisted_by_user, scheme, password_type, times_used, form_data, date_synced, display_name, icon_url, federation_url, skip_zero_click, generation_upload_status, possible_username_pairs, id, date_last_used, moving_blocked_for) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Is this connected? I do not have sqlite installed.

Linux version 5.11.0-27-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-019) (gcc (Ubuntu
9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34)
#29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021

Comment: Could be something trying to run from one of your startup rc files. Could you give the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file in your question?

Comment: It's too long to enter here, unless there's another way. What should I look for? Does anyone know what Skia shader is?

Comment: Pastebin should be fine...

Comment: Well, I get such an error too when starting Skype. The Sype-dialog stalls. The skype-startup.log shows libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[3426:1201/102219.054877:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[3426:1201/102219.262488:ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(73)] Skia shader compilation error
------------------------
#version 100